# Traverse through vertices using SELECT query, just like MATCH. Is it possible?

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2, orientdb-2.1, orientdb-etl

Traverse through vertices using SELECT query, just like MATCH. Is it possible in OrientDB?

Comment: See: https://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Traverse.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT statement allows you to traverse relationships using out()/in()/both() methods, eg. find friends of friends:

```
SELECT expand(out("FriendOf").out("FriendOf")) from Person WHERE name = 'John'
```

The SELECT in general is much less flexible than a MATCH, but it's powerful enough for basic use cases